Sorting data from Tableau REST API
I am retrieving Tableau view data via the REST API. I can filter for the data I want by appending a view filter. Example URL
http://test.tableau.com/api/3.21/sites/12345/views/6789/data?vf_Start%20Date=2024-01-11&vf_End%20Date=2024-01-30

As per the Tableau documentation, I should be able to also sort the returned data on any of the  filter fields. Example URL
http://test.tableau.com/api/3.21/sites/12345/views/6789/data?vf_Start%20Date=2024-01-11&vf_End%20Date=2024-01-30&sort=Start%20Date:asc

The data never comes back sorted however, no matter which field I choose or which direction, asc or desc.
Has anyone managed to get this to work ? Thank you
